# Apt is attempting to remove sudo package

Tags: ubuntu, apt, sudo, package-management

My machine:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Hello, I'm just trying to run
`sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-daemon-system libvirt-clients bridge-utils`, but it shows:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  adb android-libadb aptitude firefox libavformat-dev libavformat58 libchromaprint1 libgme0 libopenmpt0 libreoffice-gnome
  libreoffice-sdbc-mysql libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql libxapian30 printer-driver-brlaser qemu-utils sudo thermald thunderbird
  thunderbird-gnome-support thunderbird-locale-en thunderbird-locale-en-us
```

Note: It is trying to remove adb and sudo as well.

Is this a bug?

My intention is to solve some error in AVD manager.

Any help?

Comment: Post the full output. Did you add a PPA or other third-party repository?

Comment: @muru is almost certainly on the right track - the only reason it would try to remove `sudo` and `aptitude` in this case would be a dependency conflict somewhere, which *shouldn't be happening* unless you're mixing repositories that shouldn't be mixed.

Comment: @Shadur Oh, I think I have to remove some of the packages right?

Comment: No, you should remove whatever repository you have added that is causing a conflict.

Comment: I just resetted the sources file to default.. Now it works like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to my problem:

Reset the sources file to default

Delete `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, then recreate again.

Open Software and Packages, check the sources there...